# "PCM audio (channels 3 & 4 also)" Please help, what does this mean?

Tags: pcm

Hi there, I've been commissioned to do some sound design work on a DVD documentary, which is possibly going to be mass produced.

I've been forwarded an email via the editor asking for the files to be delivered as per the following:-

***"We ideally need files to be supplied as PCM audio (channels 3 & 4 also)"***

If anybody could provide some clarity on what they mean, that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanking you in advance,

Keith

Answer (score 1):

PCM audio is the nowadays common method of encoding analog audio to a digital form (without data compression, i.e. we're talking about "lossless digital audio"). Practically PCM audio is contained in (or "is equal to") audio formats such WAV and AIFF. Usually WAV.

Channels 3&4 might refer to the so called M&E (music & effects) track. I.e. it's a stereo bounce that has only the music and sound effects, but no voice/dialogue. It's (or can be) used to prepare e.g. localized versions. Might be a good idea to verify, whether that's what they mean.